# Indention error in jade

Tags: express, pug

This is my jade template. When I try to test following jade code @http://jade-lang.com/ it shows indention error

```
html(ng-app='testApp2', lang='en')
  head(ng-app = testApp2)
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js')
    title!= title
  body(ng-controller = 'mainController as vm')
      script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/js/app.js')
     {{ vm.massage }}
     ul
     li(ng-repeat='person in vm.person')
     {{person.name}}
```

After I run the app following error shows

```
Jade:8
    6|       script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/js/app.js')
    7|      {{ vm.massage }}
  > 8|      ul
    9|      li(ng-repeat='person in vm.person')
    10|      {{person.name}}

unexpected token "indent"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your li should lie inside ul

```
  html(ng-app='testApp2', lang='en')
     head(ng-app = testApp2)
         script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js')
         script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/js/app.js')
         title!= title
     body(ng-controller = 'mainController as vm')

       {{ vm.massage }}
       ul
          li(ng-repeat='person in vm.person')
          {{person.name}}
```

now my code looks like this

```
html(ng-app='testApp2', lang='en')
  head(ng-app = testApp2)
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js')
    title!= title
  body(ng-controller = 'mainController as vm')
      script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/js/app.js')

ul
     li(ng-repeat='person in vm.person'){{person.name}}
```